# Custom .aspx pages in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: master-page, custom

I need to deploy a custom aspx page to Sharepoint 2010 using Visual Studio. So far I added a new Sharepoint 2010 page and I see the new page in my 14 hive.
However, I can't figure out how I can access this page from Sharepoint?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've added your ASPX page to a "Layouts" mapped folder, you can access it at any site collection or subsite level, by adding /_layouts/ProjectName/YourAppFile.aspx to url of your site, such as:

```
 http://webapp/sites/sitecollection/subsite/_layouts/ProjectName/ApplicationPage.aspx
```